# Como verificar se todos os valores de um array são Number

Tags: javascript, array

gostaria de colocar uma condicional, para verificar se um determinado **array**, é composto apenas por ***Number***.

O meu **array** esta dessa forma:

```
let arrayTeste = [1, 3, 4, 6, 80, 33, 23, 90]; //apenas com Number
```

Mas se eu declarasse um **array** de ***String***:

```
let arrayTeste = ["1", "3", "4", "6", "80", "33", "23", "90"];
```

Como poderia colocar na minha função, uma condição para verificar se o **array** é diferente de ***Number***?

Tentei colocar uma condição na minha função dessa forma:

```
if (array != Number) return "Insira um array valido!";
```

mas não funcionou, mesmo eu declarando o array apenas com ***Number***, quando chamo a função, ela cai nesse **IF**, entendendo que o meu **array** é diferente de ***Number***, mesmo ele estando da forma correta:

```
let arrayTeste = [1, 3, 4, 6, 80, 33, 23, 90];
```

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como posso estar arrumando essa condição pra ela validar corretamente?

Comment: Se você quer checar o tipo de uma variável, use `typeof variavel === "number"`, `Number` é um objeto e não serve para checagem de tipo. Adicionalmente, você pode usar `Number(variavel)` para converter uma string em número e usar `Number.isNaN(variavel)` para checar se o número resultante é válido

Answer (score 1):

Como que você quer checar se algum elemento da lista é diferente do tipo **Number**, é necessário utilizar o `typeof`.

#### Código

Segue o código, onde tenho um `array` que contém valores do tipo `String`, e percorro ela utilizando o `every` e verificando se contém algum valor diferente do tipo `Number`, caso não contenha elemento do tipo  `Number` no array, me retorna `true`.

```
// array com valores Strings
let  array  = ["a", "b", "c"]

// Verificando se contém algum elemento diferente do tipo Number
console.log(array.every(function(elem) {return  typeof  elem  !==  'number';}));
```